# How to detect whether URL contains adult or illegal content?

Tags: api

Is there any API out there that checks for adult or illegal content?

I'm currently using google's browse safe api to check for malware & phishing.

However, I would like to check whether it is adult. Similar to Google's SafeSearch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Due to potential redirections (e.g. bit.ly links) and constantly changing content this could be a fruitless en devour.  What's the intended goal? - Are you trying to lock kids out of content?... if you manage the LAN, something like OpenDNS would work much better.

Comment: Hi. thx. No, we have a form where the user fills in their homepage. We want to check whether this page is legit (no adult/illegal/malware/etc).

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of companies out there that provide automatic url classification services, however nearly all of them cost money.

I've had a bit of interaction with [Zvelo](http://zvelo.com/) which it seems to be quite good and has a large database of classified urls. Again. its a paid sevice, so I'm not sure if that meets your criteria.

From a quick google search I also found;

- [ClearSwift](http://www.clearswift.com/support/url-classifications/) - Paid
- [Alhem Distributed Url Classification Tool](http://www.alhem.net/duct/) - Free
- [WebSense](http://www.websense.com/content/urlcategories.aspx) - Paid

Just bear in mind that no system is going to be 100% and that you'll get some false positives and negatives.